# Eigenvalues of specific matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> $A$ is a $n\times n$ matrix with elements in field $\textbf{k}$, such that $A^{T} = A^2$. Find all possible eigenvalues of $A$.

It is pretty easy to get $A^4=A$ from $A^{T}=A^2$, and then eigenvalue $\lambda$ must satisfy $\lambda=0,\;\lambda=1$ or $\lambda^3=1$. Examples for first two can be found easily, however I am not sure if every $\lambda^3=1$ can be eigenvalue of some matrix, could you help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Eigenvalues of such matrix $A^2 = A^T$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2667795/eigenvalues-of-such-matrix-a2-at).

Comment: But what about general case?

Comment: Check the answers for a general field $K$. So which fields contain the roots of $t^3-1$? Over $\Bbb F_3$, all roots are in the field, for example, because $t^3-1=(t-1)^3$.